# CSS advanced styling (borders, backgrounds on line features)

Tags: html, css, geojson

I have an geojson line, which I'm able to style via CSS. I've made an animated line with dashes. What I need is to show a background for this line and maybe borders for that line.

This is my CSS for the line feature. It is not an area so border [w3schools CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) and background doesn't work for me. Is there any possibility / css-propoerty to have an advanced styling, without the usage of any other library?

Can I clone the feature not in Javascript but in CSS, so I can draw the line twice with different styling?

In my case the line is a geoJson Feature, I'm using leaflet to display them in the map.

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

#conveyingForward {stroke-width: 8; -webkit-animation: dash 10s linear infinite; animation: dash 10s linear infinite; stroke-dasharray: 1,3; stroke: #006100; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show what you're talking about?